# unable to cleanly close the QDialog in PyQT using Esc Key

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a simple login application which prompts user for username and password. 
there are 2 buttons, one for logging in and other for cancel.

in the slot for the cancel button, I have the following code

```
self.cancelbutton.clicked.connect(self.closeIt)

def closeIt(self):
    self.close()
```

however when I hit the Esc Key, or click the 'X' in the QDialog, the application window disappears, but I do not get the command prompt back.

following is the code for the main function

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = x_LoginForm()
form.exec_()
form.close()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am not able to work out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `sys.exit()`.  That will immediately exit out of python.  Also, it doesn't really make much sense to call `form.exec_()` and then call `app.exec_()`

You should only need the `app.exec_()`

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = x_LoginForm()
form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks Brendan, your reply gave me some idea of what I was doing wrong.  sys.exit(form.exec_())
sys.exit(app.exec_())
basically, python was waiting for the code to exit the form, that I had instantiated earlier

Comment: however that leads to another question, Is there a way to force all running threads to be closed, so when I hit Esc key or click the 'X' button, the program exits cleanly.

Comment: Did you create the threads using `QThreads`?  They have methods to kill them or wait for them to finish -- `.wait(), .quit(), .terminate()`

Comment: yes, I am using QThreads, will check the code to ensure, I have closed all of them. thanks again for your help.